# Retrieve cell data from grid view to output in textbox VB ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a website on Visual studio 2010. i am creating it on asp.net with Visual Basic coding. I am a university student and am a beginner with this.

Basically i created a sqlDataSource and a Grid View and linked them together with drop down boxes so that the user can refine their table results. On the grid viewer i also turned on the 'select' feature so that the user can select a row.

What i am struggling to do is to retrieve at least one of the cells of the selected row in the grid view and put it into a textbox on the same page. The main cell i want to retrive is the ID so that i can use later.

Please could you help me find a suitable solution for this.

Thank you

Comment: please see if my answer worked for you and if yes then please mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in C# but the event is the same that you will target. When the user selects a row, this event will be fired and it will retrieve the selected row. Once you have the selected row you could get any column value of that row by using the index of the column.

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridView1 row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    // You could access any cell in the row by doing row.cells(index)
    MessageLabel.Text = "You selected " + row.Cells[2].Text + ".";
}
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**

**VB**

```
Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.SelectedRow

    MessageLabel.Text = "You selected " & row.Cells(2).Text & "."

  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this solution is the one that i have been long looking for. :)